# my LaCie 500 Gb not mounted on 11.10

Tags: 11.10, 11.04, usb, mount, automount

My external USB drive was recognized with 10.x versions of Ubuntu but since 11.x I am getting stuck, I had tried everything I read in forums but still the same error:

```
 4956.401052] usb 2-1.4: new high speed USB device number 14 using ehci_hcd
[ 4956.539216] scsi14 : uas
[ 4956.740955] scsi 14:0:0:0: Direct-Access     LaCie    Rugged FW USB3   1081 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[ 4963.256055] scsi 14:0:0:0: uas_eh_abort_handler tag 0
[ 4963.256076] scsi 14:0:0:0: uas_eh_device_reset_handler tag 0
[ 4963.256085] scsi 14:0:0:0: uas_eh_target_reset_handler tag 0
[ 4963.256091] scsi 14:0:0:0: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler tag 0
[ 4963.328122] usb 2-1.4: reset high speed USB device number 14 using ehci_hcd
[ 4963.468743] scsi 14:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[ 4963.468813] scsi 14:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 4963.468831] scsi 14:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 4963.469204] scsi 14:0:0:1: uas_sense_old: urb length 26 disagrees with IU sense data length 510, using 18 bytes of sense data
[ 4963.512104] sd 14:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[ 4994.253779] sd 14:0:0:0: uas_eh_abort_handler tag 0
[ 4994.253802] sd 14:0:0:0: uas_eh_device_reset_handler tag 0
[ 4994.253809] sd 14:0:0:0: uas_eh_target_reset_handler tag 0
[ 4994.253815] sd 14:0:0:0: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler tag 0
[ 4994.325880] usb 2-1.4: reset high speed USB device number 14 using ehci_hcd
[ 4994.466488] sd 14:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[ 4994.466555] sd 14:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 4994.466573] sd 14:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 4994.466582] sd 14:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 4994.466588] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdc] READ CAPACITY failed
[ 4994.466593] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdc]  Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 4994.466600] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
[ 4994.466608] sd 14:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 4994.466616] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[ 4994.466622] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[ 4994.466629] sd 14:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 4994.466635] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdc] Asking for cache data failed
[ 4994.466640] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 4994.467003] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
```

if I am trying on an old ubuntu, the drive is mounted,

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are experiencing this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/875523).
Looking to the bug description, I guess a possible workaround is to backport the kernel to version 2.6.35.